# How to apply += operator inside a conditional ternary operator

Tags: vb.net

Having a list View in Vb, and having a variable total8KI how can I accumulate its value but checking if it is not null or empty at the same time?

I would like to accomplish something like

```
Dim total8KI As Double
For Each itm As ListViewItem In lv.Items
   total8KI += CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text)
Next
```

But adding condition if is null or empty assign 0 else assign the value so

```
Dim total8KI As Double
For Each itm As ListViewItem In lv.Items
   IIf(total8KI = String.IsNullOrEmpty(CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text)), CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text), 0)
Next
```

The problem is that I can not apply `+=` inside ternaru operator

Is there a way to acomplish this in one line or Do I have to use

```
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text))) Then
        total8KI += CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text)
    Else
        total8KI += 0
    End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the new `IF` (not supported in old versions of VB.NET):

```
total8KI += If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(itm.SubItems(27).Text), CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text), 0)
```

Or safer:

```
total8KI += If(IsNumeric(itm.SubItems(27).Text), CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text), 0)
```

if you expect non-empty, non-numeric values could be there.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

`IIf(total8KI = String.IsNullOrEmpty(CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text)), CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text), 0)`

To

`total8KI+=If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text)), CDbl(itm.SubItems(27).Text), 0)`

Comment: This can still cause exception, becuz `IIF` function evaluates both true and false arguments whatever the value of condition may be.